# Passing array pointers to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Why should I use `*&` after the type name (`T*&`) in the following code? Isn't `a` a pointer to a pointer? If it is, then why should I not use `**` instead?

```
template <class T> void CreateArray(T*& a, int n)
{
   a = new double[n];
}

int main()
{
  double* a;
  CreateArray<double>(a,3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a *reference* to a pointer

Comment: No, it's a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Would you agree with Oli?  It seems like you're asking how a reference acts differently than a pointer.

Comment: Note that you don't really want to use *any* of the above. `std::vector<double> a(3);` is the right way to accomplish what you're doing above.

Comment: I want to know the reason why I should add the `&` to the pointer. From what I understand, it enables me to edit the pointer's address (using `new`), am I right?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth No, that question does not address my problem. I know how pointers and references work but I still have trouble when it comes to passing array pointers to functions. It would be great if someone explained that to me.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: But in that case, which part are you having trouble with?  You have a reference to a variable.  That variable happens to be a pointer.  That's all.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth It makes me able to edit the pointer's address (using `new`), right?

Comment: @MohammadSanei: You're modifying the pointer, not its address...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth So why should I make a reference to it if I am modifying the pointer itself?

Comment: @MohammadSanei: Because otherwise you would be modifying a copy...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Now I get it! I thought pointers to arrays were different from pointers to other data types because of the fact that the name of an array itself represents a pointer. That was why I thought I needed to use a pointer to a pointer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't a a pointer to a pointer?

No, it is a reference to a pointer.

> then why should I not use ** instead?

You could do this, but it makes the usage, both on the calling side and within the function, a bit more complicated.  However, you could write a function with the same overall effect in either way.

Comment: references are also safer, a pointer is just a variable that stores an address, and that address it's not necessarily a valid, readable, location in memory, it can also be something that you are NOT looking for.

Comment: @user2384250: In practice, there's no guarantee that a reference refers to a valid object either...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well, we leave the "good practice" to the programmer, didn't we ?

Comment: @user2384250: It's not (just) a question of "good practice". It's also a question of not accidentally creating an invalid reference, e.g by deleting an object, modifying a container, or dereferencing a null pointer. (Although of course there are "good practices" which can help avoid doing these things).

Answer (score 2):

`T*&` is a reference to a pointer, now while references behind the scenes may be implemented as a pointer, it is not the same thing as a `T**`. You can definitely use a `T **` to accomplish the same thing but it would not be idiomatic C++ and it would not be as simple, using references allows you to not worry about how to pass by reference.

Comment: To add to Shafik's excellent summation, while passing a pointer by reference doesn't seem like a big deal, passing a reference to an arbitrary class allows you to use simpler syntax and semantics, and presents a safer, easier, and more maintainable way to use arguments as output parameters.  Love references, embrace them, use them instead of pointers when you can.

Comment: How would using `T**` be less idiomatic or less simple (disregarding the few extra characters). I can definetly see a case for `T**` over `T*&` here, since the former makes it explicit to the caller that the function might modify the pointer while you can't differentiate between `T*&` and `T*` parameters when looking at the calling code. Of course the code is horrible either way, but that is really beside the point.